# Update banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Então tenho um modal que mostra os dados do número que foi pesquisado, eu quero que ao clicar no botao editar do modal libere os inputs: funcionario, rca e regiao para poder escrever dentro desses inputs e também o botao salvar para realizar o update no banco de dados, eu já fiz a pagina que atualiza...

código do modal:

```html
<?php
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados

if(!empty($_POST['numerodigitado'])){

    $numerodigitado = $_POST['numerodigitado'];

    $result = "SELECT * FROM tb_numeros WHERE numero = '$numerodigitado' ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    if($resultado -> num_rows > 0){
  echo"
  <div class='modal fade' id='squarespaceModa2' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
   <div class='modal-dialog'>
   <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
     <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
        
    <div class='modal-body'>
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-3'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
       
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
       
       <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-7'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='btn-group btn-group-justified' role='group' aria-label='group button'>
      <div class='btn-group' role='group'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' role='button'>Editar</button>
     </div>
      <div class='btn-group' role='group'>
      <input class='btn btn-success btn-hover-green' role='button' type='submit' value='Cadastrar' name='Salvar'>
      </div>
     </div>
   
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ $('#squarespaceModa2').modal(); });  
  </script>";
    
    } 
 else {
       echo "<script>
   alert('Número não encontrado.');
   window.location='index.php';
  </script>"; 
    }
}

?>
```

pagina atualizar.php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("../conn/conexao.php");
 
 $numero = $_GET["numero"];
 
 $funcionario= $_POST["funcionario"];
 $rca= $_POST["rca"];
 $regiao= $_POST["regiao"];
 $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
 
 $up = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE tb_numeros SET funcionario='$funcionario', rca=$rca, regiao='$regiao', usuario='$nome'  WHERE numero = $numero ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
 
 if($up):
  echo "<script>
    alert('Alterado com sucesso.');
    window.location='index.php';
   </script>"; 
 else:
  echo "<script>
    alert('Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar, entre em contato com o administrador.');
    window.location='index.php';
   </script>";
 endif;
?>
```

Comment: Qual está sendo o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Atribua um id para o botão:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' role='button' id='btnEditar'>Editar</button>
```

E faça um javascript para habilitar os campos.

```
$('#btnEditar').on('click', function(){
    $(input[name="funcionario"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
    $(input[name="rca"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
    $(input[name="regiao"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
});
```

adicione um form com a action para a pagina que atualiza:

```
    echo"
        <div class='modal fade' id='squarespaceModa2' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
            <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>

                <div class='modal-body'>
<form method="post" action="atualizar.php">
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-3'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-7'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='btn-group btn-group-justified' role='group' aria-label='group button'>
                        <div class='btn-group' role='group'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' role='button' id='btnEditar'>Editar</button>
                    </div>
                        <div class='btn-group' role='group'>
                        <input class='btn btn-success btn-hover-green' role='button' type='submit' value='Cadastrar' name='Salvar'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ $('#squarespaceModa2').modal(); });  
        </script>";
```

Comment: Esse form vai a onde ? Já que já tenho um form para mostrar os dados buscado

Comment: Vai dentro do body da sua modal, vou editar e resposta. @Ferb

Comment: ainda não funcionou quando clico no botão editar

Comment: Mas ele não liberou os campos para alteração? Verificou no console se está dando algum erro?

Comment: não liberou os campos, não fez nada

Comment: tente alterar o código do botão editar para esse: 
<script>
        $('document').on('click','#btnEditar', function(){
        $(input[name="funcionario"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
        $(input[name="rca"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
        $(input[name="regiao"]).removeAttr('readyonly');
    });
</script>

Comment: nada ainda, não sei o que fazer

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69351/discussion-between-arllondias-and-ferb).